# Set up a friend sharespace using Linux Group and User permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I would like to set up a linux share space in the following way:
I want one user lets call admin to have access to all other users home directories.
I want to be able to create users A,B,C,D,E and have none of them view any other folders except there home folder(and /tmp/ if needed).
I do not want them to be able to view any other files.
I will use this so I can create a user for them they can log in view/edit a file in their home folder and nothing else(or scp a file into it)

How do I do this?
My first thought was to create a group and put them all in that group but I do not want them to be able to view each other’s files.
I notice that the folders in /home/*  are only read,write,execute by the owner:

```
[test2@XXX home]$ pwd
/home
[test2@XXX home]$ ll
drwx------  3 test2       test2        4096 Mar  7 18:54 test2
```

Is this sufficient permissions then?
The files in /home/A/ for example are

```
[test2@XXX~]$ pwd
/home/test2
[test2@XXX~]$ ll
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 test2 test2 4096 Mar  7 18:54 testdir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 test2 test2    0 Mar  7 18:54 testfile
```

User B would not be able to write to these files correct?
If so what do I need to do in order to have user admin able to view all these /home/ folders but nobody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need a user "Admin" who will have rwx permissions on all home directories of users A, B, C, D, E. Here I am assuming that your "Admin" user is not **root**.

You can refer to this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/532332/how-to-give-user-rwx-access-to-another-user) for achieving this functionality.

Now you don't want any of the user A, B, C, D, E to see each others' files, but a **Public** folder exists in your Home directory (**/home/user**) for sharing files with other users. If an other user wants to get access to this Public folder, the execute bit for the world should be set on the Home directory.

If you do not need to allow others to access your home folder (other humans or users like **www-data** for a webserver), you'll be fine with **chmod o-rwx "$HOME"** (remove read/write/execute from "other", equivalent to **chmod 750 "$HOME"** since the default permission is 750). Otherwise, you should change the umask setting too to prevent newly created files from getting read permissions for the world by default.

For a system-wide configuration, edit **/etc/profile**; per-user settings can be configured in **~/.profile**. I prefer the same policy for all users, so I'd edit the **/etc/profile** file and append the line:

> umask 027

You need to re-login to apply these changes, unless you're in a shell. In that case, you can run **umask 027** in the shell.

Now to fix the existing permissions, you need to remove the read/write/execute permissions from other:

> chmod -R o-rwx ~

Now if you decide to share the **~/Public** folder to everyone, run the next commands:

- **chmod o+x ~ -** allow everyone to descend in the directory (**x**), but not get a directory listing (**r** should not be added)
- **find ~/Public -type f -exec chmod o+r {} \;** - allow everyone to read the files in **~/Public**
- **find ~/Public -type d -exec chmod o+rx {} \;** - allow everyone to descend into directories and list their contents

Comment: Thanks Pulkit, I ended up making one user, the public user and then adding everyone else to that users subgroup.  I also added another user (me) to the subgroup of everyone else’s accounts.  I then chmod g+rwx on the home dir of the new user after creation.  I created a simple script to do this.  I appreciate the help!